# Erlang Linux signal handling

Tags: linux, erlang, signals

Is it possible to trap Linux signals (e.g. SIGUSR1) through an handler in Erlang? (without having to resort to a driver crafted in C)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(NOT A REAL ANSWER)

In 2001 someone asked:

> Does anyone have any examples of unix
>   signal handling in erlang. I would
>   like to make a loadbalancer that I
>   have written respond to sighup.

At that time the answer was:

> There is no provision for handling
>   signals in Erlang "itself", i.e. you
>   will need to use a driver - or a port
>   program of course, might actually be a
>   better idea. Also for the driver case,
>   the emulator has its own handler for a
>   number of signals, and interfering
>   with that will probably have
>   "interesting" results - but SIGHUP
>   should be OK I believe.

SOURCE: http://www.erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2001-October/003752.html

As far as I know, nothing changed since then. But this is extremely interesting. If anyone has any news about this, please let us know :)

Answer (score 4):

This is possible since Erlang/OTP 20.0, released in June 2017.  It was done through [this pull request](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/1315) that adds an event manager for signals called `erl_signal_server`.  See the "OS Signal Event Handler" section in [the `kernel` manual page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html).

If you're interested in SIGUSR1, note that the default handler will make the Erlang VM halt and produce a crash dump.  To avoid that, it's not enough to add your own handler to `erl_signal_server`; you have to swap the default handler for it:

```
gen_event:swap_handler(erl_signal_server, {erl_signal_handler, []}, {foo, []}).
```